# Can't open Gajim

Tags: terminal, gnome, python, gajim

When I try to open Gajim using terminal on gnome I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gajim.py", line 106, in <module>
    import common.configpaths
  File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/configpaths.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

Any idea how to fix this?

My OS is Mandriva 2010.1, Python is v2.6 upgraded from v2.4

Comment: Can you include more details about your OS (distribution, version) and the version of python on your machine to help in solving the problem?

Comment: My OS is Mandriva 2010.1, Python is v2.6 upgraded from v2.4

Comment: Better add add it to the question

Comment: @Bichoy thx for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably importing the wrong os.py module. Try starting python2.6
and then

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.__file__
```

That should be `/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py` or `/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc`.
If it is not remove (or rename) the file that you found.
If it is try:

```
>>> os.urandom(3)
```

This should give you a string of 3 characters. If it does, then `gajim` is finding the wrong `os.py` module. If you get the same error as when running `gajim` then look in the `/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py` at the end `urandom` should be defined if it does not exist ( using the line `if not _exists("urandom":`).

If it is not defined, as seems to be the case for `python-2.6.5-2.5mdv2010.2.x86_64`, and `/dev/urandom` exists you could try to re-add the code:

```
if not _exists("urandom"):
    def urandom(n):
        """urandom(n) -> str

        Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

        """
        try:
            _urandomfd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)
        except (OSError, IOError):
            raise NotImplementedError("/dev/urandom (or equivalent) not found")
        try:
            bs = b""
            while n - len(bs) >= 1:
                bs += read(_urandomfd, n - len(bs))
        finally:
            close(_urandomfd)
        return bs
```

See also: [this](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/87) bug report

Comment: I got: `/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc`

Comment: I updated the things to test in the answer.

Comment: `>>> os.urandom(3)` got me this:

`>>> os.urandom(3)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urandom'

>>> 

`

Comment: can you look at the last 20 lines or so of /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py? That should have the if statement in there.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find `if not _exists("urandom":)` in os.py

Comment: Which version of 2.6 did you install ( I have been looking at 2.6, self-compiled, running under Ubuntu 8.04 ).

Comment: python-2.6.5-2.5mdv2010.2.x86_64

Comment: That is definitely in the 2.6.5 source distribution, so mandriva took it out (also reported [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/201039)). Looks like that mandriva version does not have `/dev/urandom` for some reason.

Comment: But I found that `urandom` exists in the directory `/dev`

Comment: I get offers to move this discussion to chat, but unfortunately you have not enough reputation to be able write there. I added the lines from the source distribution, can you add those to your os.py?